# How to update a SQL table using multiple condition of the same table?

Tags: sql

I am trying to update the table.

1. Starting with row 1 where Trf = 0 with Max# 5
2. Update Row# 6 Trf from 11 to 0, with Max# 13
3. Update Row# 14 Trf from 11 to 0
4. Continue to iterate through the table until the rows are updated

I tried to use do the following, but it only update the first instance, so i need to repeat this multiple times to update the whole table.

```
SELECT
    a.[Row]
    , CASE
        WHEN COALESCE(b.[Row], -1) = -1 THEN a.Trf
        ELSE 0
        END AS Trf
    , Min#
    , Max#
FROM #SampleTable AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
#SampleTable AS b
ON a.[row] = b.[Max#]
AND b.Trf = 0
```

| Row | Trf | Min# | Max# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 11 | 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 11 | 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 11 | 4 | 11 |
| 5 | 11 | 5 | 12 |
| 6 | 11 | 6 | 13 |
| 7 | 11 | 7 | 15 |
| 8 | 11 | 8 | 16 |
| 9 | 11 | 9 | 16 |
| 10 | 11 | 10 | 18 |
| 11 | 11 | 11 | 19 |
| 12 | 11 | 12 | 19 |
| 13 | 11 | 13 | 22 |
| 14 | 11 | 14 | 24 |
| 15 | 11 | 15 | 25 |

Comment: what's the logic to update those rows? It's not clear. also you are not updating you are just showing it as 0 , do you really want to update ? or it is just the matter of presentation?

Comment: The logic the following: 1) Start with the first row that has Trf = 0, take its Max# value + 1 (5+1), and update that row from Trf = 11 to 0.  Repeat this process until all the identified rows are 0.  My solution is trying update the row, so that I can repeat the process multiple times, but if there is a way of just showing it, that would work too.